# Deleted context link still exists in admin toolbar menu

Tags: 9, configuration, toolbar

I have deleted context but in admin toolbar it still showing . On main context admin page context doesn't exists. I have installed/uninstalled module - not helping

How do i remove that link from toolbar menu?

[image]

Comment: Which module did you uninstall? You must rebuild cache of the site to pull the new changes.

Comment: Did you try clear the cache?

Comment: yes i have cleared cache via admin panel and via drush 

i have tried to uninstall and install back admin toolbar module ... no effect

Comment: @prkos i have uninstalled admin toolbar and yes i have rebuild cache - no effect

Comment: Also i have tried uninstall admin toolbar module completely with composer and installed again ... bug still exists. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely i got solved it...

After research and very useful comment on dropal.org I came across to the right answer.
I have posted a bug on Admin toolbar project https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_toolbar/issues/3348914 and one of the comment actually explained to me what happening. Here is a problem with the context menu builder.
here is the link https://www.drupal.org/project/context/issues/3284359 on this bug

How do i got fixed ... i didn't applied the patch. I  just recreated the contexts with the exact machine name and after saving deleted it ....
That fixed my issue.